# AJAX GET returns undefined on the first call, but works on the second one

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am working on a real estate web app in ASP.NET MVC. My problem is in my Reservations section. [image]

I am using AJAX to post in a Controller which returns a `JSONResult`. Here is my code:

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult SubmitReservation(ReservationViewModel rvm)
{
    return Json(rvm, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

**Main AJAX**

```
    var rvm = new ReservationViewModel();

    getBuyerInfo(rvm.SelectedBuyerID, clientCallback);
    getSiteInfo(rvm.SelectedSiteID, siteCallback);
    getUnitInfo(rvm.SelectedUnitID, unitCallback);

    $.ajax({
        url: "/Reservations/SubmitReservation",
        data: JSON.stringify(rvm),
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function () {

            console.log(clientData);
            console.log(siteData);
            console.log(unitData);
            //Assignment of data to different output fields

            //Client Data
            $('#clientName').html(clientData.FullName);
            $('#clientAddress').html(clientData.Residence);
            $('#clientContact').html(clientData.ContactNumber);

            //Site Data
            $('#devSite').html(siteData.SiteName);
            $('#devLoc').html(siteData.Location);

            ////House Unit Data
            $('#unitBlock').html(unitData.Block);
            $('#unitLot').html(unitData.Lot);
            $('#modelName').html(unitData.ModelName);
            $('#modelType').html(unitData.TypeName);
            $('#lotArea').html(unitData.LotArea);
            $('#floorArea').html(unitData.FloorArea);
            $('#unitBedrooms').html(unitData.NumberOfBedrooms);
            $('#unitBathrooms').html(unitData.NumberOfBathrooms);
            $('#unitPrice').html(unitData.Price);

            $('#reservationDetails').show();
            alert("Success!");
        },
        error: function (err) {
            alert("Error: " + err);
        }
    });
```

**Functions for fetching data**

```
function getBuyerInfo(id, cb) {
   $.ajax({
       url: "/BuyersInformation/GetBuyerByID/" + id,
       type: "GET",
       contentType: "application/json",
       dataType: "json",
       success: cb
  });
 }

function getSiteInfo(id, cb) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Sites/GetSiteByID/" + id,
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        success: cb
     });
 }

function getUnitInfo(id, cb) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/HouseUnits/GetUnitByID/" + id,
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        success: cb
     });
  }

function ReservationViewModel() {

var buyerId = $('#SelectedBuyerID').val();
var siteId = $('#SelectedSiteID').val();
var unitId = $('#SelectedUnitID').val();
var rsvDate = $('#ReservationDate').val();

var me = this;
me.ReservationDate = rsvDate;
me.SelectedBuyerID = buyerId;
me.SelectedSiteID = siteId;
me.SelectedUnitID = unitId;

}

function clientCallback(result) {
    clientInfo = result;
    clientData = clientInfo[0];
 }

function siteCallback(result) {
   siteInfo = result;
   siteData = siteInfo[0];
 }

function unitCallback(result) {
    unitInfo = result;
    unitData = unitInfo[0];
}
```

The whole code WORKS well for the second time. However, it does not work for the FIRST time. When I refresh the page and I hit Create, it returns undefined. But when I hit that button again without refreshing the page, it works well. Can somebody explain to me this one? Why does AJAX returns undefined at first but not at succeeding calls? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe I have missed it but where is your cb function in your code?

Comment: too many places for us to look without more information. Please scale this down to only the relevant code. How is form bound to the ajax .... if that's the only problem only show that code

Comment: You can see the `cb` parameter  in the `getBuyerInfo` , `getSiteInfo` , and `getUnitInfo`. The cb parameters are declared as `clientCallback`, `siteCallback` and `unitCallback`.

Comment: @charlietfl I apologize those are somewhat several. I have included those functions because I used them in the main AJAX code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling several ajax requests in your code, inside these functions:

```
getBuyerInfo(rvm.SelectedBuyerID, clientCallback);
getSiteInfo(rvm.SelectedSiteID, siteCallback);
getUnitInfo(rvm.SelectedUnitID, unitCallback);
```

and finally `$.ajax({...})` after them, where you use results from pervious ajax calls.

Your problem is that the first ajax calls do not necessarily return results before your start the last ajax because they are all async. You have to make sure you get three responds before calling the last ajax. Use promises or jQuery `when`, like this:

```
var rvm = new ReservationViewModel();

$.when( 

    $.ajax({
       url: "/BuyersInformation/GetBuyerByID/" + rvm.SelectedBuyerID,
       type: "GET",
       contentType: "application/json",
       dataType: "json"
    }),

    $.ajax({
        url: "/Sites/GetSiteByID/" + rvm.SelectedSiteID,
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json"
     }),

    $.ajax({
        url: "/HouseUnits/GetUnitByID/" + rvm.SelectedUnitID,
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json"
     })

).done(function ( clientResponse, siteResponse, unitResponse ) {

    clientInfo = clientResponse;
    clientData = clientInfo[0];          

    siteInfo = siteResponse;
    siteData = siteInfo[0];

    unitInfo = unitResponse;
    unitData = unitInfo[0];          

    $.ajax({ ... }) // your last ajax call

});
```

Comment: I'm going to give this one a try.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I am looking for. I tweaked those `...Info[0]` and changed to `..Info[0][0]` and I got it working .

Answer (score 2):

`AJAX` calls are `asynchronous`. You last `ajax` call will not wait until your above 3 ajax calls finishes its work. so you can make use of **[`$.when`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/)** and `.done` here as below..

```
$.when(
    getBuyerInfo(rvm.SelectedBuyerID, clientCallback);
    getSiteInfo(rvm.SelectedSiteID, siteCallback);
    getUnitInfo(rvm.SelectedUnitID, unitCallback);
).done(
    $.ajax({
       //Ajax part
    })
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried this one but still it didn't work. :(

Comment: Atleast one of the 3 data returned are logged as `undefined` in the console.